# React: I have some behavior that applies to a wrapper that encompasses the whole project. But I want my central div to be exempt from that behavior

Tags: reactjs, events, components

In my React project, I have set my wrapping component set to listen for particular click and swiping events. However, I do not want those events to be listened for, whilst users are scrolling through the contents of a child component for this wrapper.

Can anyone point me in a direction to overcome this problem? I'm sure I'm not the first to struggle with something so general, but I couldn't think of how to phrase this question in a way to find other solutions. Probably means its time for lunch.

Thanks for your time pals!

Comment: I think you can solve this by adding the same listener to the child component and then you could stop the propagation of the event: `<AwesomeComponent onClick={ev => ev.stopPropgation()}>`. Let me know if it works!

Answer (score 0):

So what I did end up doing was locking onto the target's className that was being returned by the touch event!

```
const target = event.touches[0].target;
        if ( target.className !== "aboutClassDeployed" && target.parentElement.className !== "aboutClassDeployed") {
```